# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column [ laravel ]

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys

There are two tables (Expense and Shop).

I tried adding a new shop, but this error occurred:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'shops.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `shops` where `shops`.`user_id` in (1))

And still, I can't figure out where this issue comes from.

**My User Model**

```
<pre>
   public function expense()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Expense::class);
    }
    public function shop()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Shop::class);
    }
 </pre>
```

**My Expense Model**

```
   <pre>
        public function user()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(\App\User::class);  
        }
   </pre>
```

**Here My Shop Model**

```
  <pre>
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\User::class);
    }
  </pre>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It says you don't have `user_id` column  in your `shops` table, Check that table.

Comment: Please add to the question how are you doing the query to add the new shop.

Comment: If a `Shop` belongs to a `User` it's table should have a `foreign key` named `user_id` by convention, you can change the name in the relationship definition. Have you this kind of field in your `shops` table or migration?

Comment: is there any column named user_id in shops  table

Comment: @RakibulIslam, i found a solution, anyway thanks